# Reactivity and selectivity in free radical halogenation of alkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, radicals, regioselectivity

I read about the free radical halogenation of alkanes with $\ce{X2}$ and I have the following questions:

1. Given that the first step is the homolytic breaking of the $\ce{X-X}$ bond, and [the homolytic bond dissociation enthalpies of halogens](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/NSRDS/nbsnsrds31.pdf) (page 23, 31, and 34 of the PDF - I think it does not have data on $\ce{I-I}$ - but I'll use values from my textbook) are in the order $\ce{I_2 < F_2 < Br_2 < Cl_2}$, why is the order of reactivity of halogens $\ce{F_2 > Cl_2 > Br_2 > I_2}$?
2. My book said that bromine is very selective when reacting with alkanes - it will prefer a tertiary carbon greatly over primary or secondary ones. Chlorine is less selective and fluorine is not selective at all - it's happy to react with all types of carbons. Why is this so?

PS: I am using the textbook '[Organic Chemistry For JEE](https://www.amazon.in/Solomons-Organic-Chemistry-Advanced-2017-18/dp/B072HRZ3JV?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=d0c0ca10-7a94-4529-904b-066ba9349b9b)' by Solomons, Fryhle, and Snyder.

Comment: Related: [What determines the high degree of selectivity in free radical halogenations](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64255/7951), [Why is it possible to form bromoalkanes but not iodoalkanes from free radical substitution?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59677/7951) and [What is the major product on chlorination of 2-methylbutane?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/26949/7951)

Comment: Your order for bond dissociation energies correct (DOI: 10.1039/TF9625800633)

Comment: Also related: [Why does radical chlorination and bromination of propane occur at different positions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/93592/)